# 2 Java web applications on 2 tomcat instances (same windows machine) on different ports

Tags: tomcat, instances

I have two java web applications running on two instances of tomcat 7 on same windows machine. One application is running on port 9080 and another on 9090.

I log into both applications using 2 tabs in the SAME browser.

When I logout from one application (e.g application on 9080) I get logged out from other application (running on 9090) also.

Need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have not done the correct configuration for the web container.
Go through [this](http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server/)
First configure the web container and then follow these [instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/32715)
What IDE are you using?

Comment: Solved by giving unique name to sessions. e.g. <cookie-config><name>APP1</name>
     </cookie-config> and <cookie-config><name>APP2</name>
     </cookie-config> in web.xml in tomcat_home\conf folder. Looks like a tomcat 7 thingy.