# Session object is reset after loading a different deployment (on a different port) of the same application

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I've got two versions of the same grails application running on two instances of Tomcat (and using two different Javas) but on the same machine (under Windows).

So lets say that:

- App A1 is running on Tomcat T1 and Java J1 on Machine M on port 7224
- App A2 is running on Tomcat T2 and Java J2 on Machine M on port 8080

Here's the odd behaviour:

1. Load up App A1 on one tab
2. Load up App A2 on another tab
3. Login to A1 (I just generate a token and put it on the session through a filter)
4. Refresh tab with A2 (not having logged in)
5. Refresh tab with A1, I am logged out (the token is null).

If I use an alias hostname of Machine M (e.g. localhost:7224 and 192.168.1.1:8080) this does not occur.

Does anyone know what might make this occur?

EDIT: [found one possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828238/2-java-web-applications-on-2-tomcat-instances-same-windows-machine-on-differen?rq=1), but it is using tomcat 7 (I am using Tomcat 8). The answer there does not apply for me as my catalina has the right port configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Grails uses cookies to store session IDs. And cookies are domain-specific. That's why the the alias hostname fixes the problem. Try this:

1. Remove the alias hostname.
2. Log in to A1
3. Open the browser's list of cookies and find the one for 192.168.1.1. You should see a cookie named *JSESSIONID*. Remember the cookie's data.
4. Refresh the tab running A2.
5. Check the session cookie again. The value for *JSESSIONID* will probably be different, or maybe empty.

**How to fix it**

To address this issue, you'd have to make both apps stop competing for the *JSESSIONID* name.

For Tomcat8, in `{tomcat}/conf/context.xml` the `<Context>` node is probably empty. This makes the session cookie name to default to *JSESSIONID*. The solution is to explicitly set the `sessionCookieName`.

It should look like below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context sessionCookieName="SESSION8080">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

And you'd make a similar change for the other application `<Context sessionCookieName="SESSION7224">`

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction, thanks! I will edit it with the solution